# É possível capturar o index de um select escolhido?

Tags: javascript, html-select

Simplificando, eu tenho um select (combobox) no meu html e gostaria de saber qual indice (posição) foi escolhido. ou seja, se foi o primeiro, o segundo, o terceiro...
O motivo é que no meu ajax eu recebo um array de produtos, e o campo "preco" vai receber o valor dependendo do select escolhido.
HTML:

```
<select class="form-control" id="selectProdutos">
   <option selected>Escolha uma opção</option>
 </select>
```

Javascript:

```
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
         $('#selectProdutos').append('<option>' + data[i].descricao + '</option>');
      }
```

Comment: Você deveria incluir uma propriedade `value` nos seus elementos `<option>`, depois basta buscar o `value` do `<select>`, que terá o mesmo valor do `<option>` selecionado.

Comment: Voce salvou minha noite, muito obrigado. Nao sei como curtir ou aceitar sua resposta

Answer (score 1):

Os itens da sua lista precisam ter o atributo `value` para funcionar

```
<select class="form-control" id="selectProdutos">
    <option value="null" selected>Escolha uma opção</option>
    <option value="Opcao 1">Opção 1</option>
    <option value="Opcao 2">Opção 2</option>
    <option value="Opcao 3">Opção 3</option>
</select>
```

No javascript você pode acessar o valor do input assim:

```
var lista = document.getElementById("selectProdutos");
var valor = lista.value;
console.log(valor);
```

lista.value retorna o valor do seu select no determinado momento. `Console.Log()` serve para mandar esse valor pro console para visualização. Espero que tenha resolvido, qualquer duvida só chamar. :)